# Tab bar within Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a navigation based app, in one of the screen I now want to add a tab bar. Can any one please share code snippet on how I can do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the common way is to add a navigation view to one within a tab view, not vice versa. as far as i know it is not possible to add a tab bar to a navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a modal view that uses an underlying tab bar. Another idea is to use the tab bar for the whole app and hide the bar for the views where you don't want it to show up.